# Angular: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, deployment, angular-ui-bootstrap, aws-amplify

I am working on an angular 9 project where I implemented self-designed user authentication using AWS Amplify with the help of the following steps: https://gerard-sans.medium.com/build-your-first-full-stack-serverless-app-with-angular-and-aws-amplify-d2e4716de9bd. Also, I integrated graphQL in the backend. And the whole project runs fine locally and throws an error on deployment. It shows the following error on deployment.

[image]

I am using the following angular dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.12",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.7",
    "@apollo/client": "^3.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.31",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.0",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^7.9.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.4",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^16.0.2",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.22",
    "angularx-flatpickr": "^6.5.1",
    "apollo-angular": "^2.1.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.19.1",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.3.13",
    "aws-amplify-angular": "^5.0.42",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.6",
    "graphql": "^15.4.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^7.0.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^11.0.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "graphql-cli": "^4.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating my Angular version from 9 to 11 worked for me.